# Two association records are being created even though it is a has_one relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

My user model and location model is in a has_one relationship but sometimes the user model has 2 location models created and since the relationship is has_one, user.location is accessing the last one. However, the 2 location objects are breaking my location controller method when updating the location.
(Rails version = 5)

Here is my Location Model

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :meeting

  validates :latitude, presence: true
  validates :longitude, presence: true
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: true, allow_nil: true
  validates :meeting_id, uniqueness: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

My question is: How to restrict Location model to created just once?

Comment: Make sure to add a unique index at the database level to ensure only one location can be set for the user since uniqueness validations won't always ensure that.  Ex. migration:   add_index :locations, :user_id, unique: true

Comment: Thanks that worked!!